# Records within date range - Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Here is a problem. I have a table

```
flightdetails
-----------+-------------
flightName | varchar(200)
departure  | date
arrival    | date
```

I want to get all the flights in the given date range. Either fromDate or toDate should be inside the given daterange. I know of a simple query which will give me the result

```
select flightname from flightdetails where (departure between fromDate and toDate)
or (arrival between fromDate and toDate);
```

But this not good for performance as I use an OR condition. Can anyone suggest a better solution which favours performance too

Comment: arrival will always be >= departure, right?

Comment: Yes . Arrival is greater that departure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common solution to this problem.  Each subquery can make use of an index this way.

```
select flightname from flightdetails where departure between fromDate and toDate
union
select flightname from flightdetails where arrival between fromDate and toDate;
```

---

Re comment from @SalmanA

You're right, the query above misses cases like this:

```
departure < fromDate < toDate < arrival
```

Since neither departure nor arrival are between the date range, but of course the date range is included in the flight time.

Here's another solution, based on yours but it makes use of indexes both on departure and arrival.  Be sure to create compound indexes for each condition:

```
create index flt_d on flightdetails(flightname, departure);
create index flt_a on flightdetails(flightname, arrival);

select f1.flightname 
from flightdetails f1
join flightdetails f2 use index (flt_a)
  on f1.flightname = f2.flightname
where f1.departure <= toDate
  and f2.arrival >= fromDate;
```

I tested this out and I had to use the "use index" hint to coax it to use the second index, but when I did I got this optimizer plan:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: f1
         type: index
possible_keys: flt_d,flt_a
          key: flt_d
      key_len: 20
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: f2
         type: ref
possible_keys: flt_a
          key: flt_a
      key_len: 12
          ref: test.f1.flightname
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggession. But still if we consider millions of data, union will slow down the things due to duplication check. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Union only needs to remove duplicates from the matching rows, not all the millions of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggession. Same question was asked to me during an interview and I told this solution also. But the interviewer was not satisfied and asking for better solution. Even I could not think anything more than this solution. Thats why wanted to check anything better available... Thanks again

Comment: Umm, what happens if departure < fromDate and toDate < arrival? Rare case but possible.

Comment: @SalmanA, good point, my query matches the logic in the OP's question but that doesn't return every flight between fromDate and toDate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use this query:

> ```
> -- 2.2) select date ranges that overlap [d1, d2] (d2 and end_date are inclusive)  
> SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE @d2 >= start_date AND end_date >= @d1
> ```

Making few substitutions e.g. start_date becomes departure, end_date becomes arrival, etc:

```
SELECT flightname
FROM   flightdetails
WHERE  toDate >= departure AND arrival >= fromDate
```

Comment: This will not return all my records. For eg. if my arrival is withing date range and depature was prior to from date, still I want to see that record. Hope I am clear enough

Comment: Try it. It should work (at least it does so when I use it to check conflicting bookings).

Comment: It returns the correct set of rows, but a single index can't benefit two range conditions.